# Agile Testing with no Acceptance Criteria or Documentation to refer to

Tags: agile-testing

I have been asked to test a new software application.  The project is run Agile.  In some cases I have no Acceptance Criteria and no documentation to refer to and I am being asked to write test cases for a User Story.
Is this even possible?  Has someone had to do this before and do you have any advice?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This is sadly not uncommon especially with newer Agile teams. I would take the proactive approach and write the Acceptance Criteria and then have it reviewed with the Product Owner (or whoever wrote the User Story) and Devs. I recommend writing it in the [Gherkin Given-When-Then](https://www.agilealliance.org/glossary/gwt/) format. The example given in the agile alliance website is like this:

> **Given** my bank account is in credit, and I made no withdrawals recently,
>
> **When** I attempt to withdraw an amount less than my card's limit,
>
> **Then** the withdrawal should complete without errors or warnings

You can have multiple ACs for a User Story. And these ACs can easily be used as test cases.

At the very least, you should raise this issue in Sprint Retrospective - the team needs to come to agreement on what is an acceptable User Story, be it more description and/or acceptance criteria. And at the next Backlog Grooming and Sprint Planning meetings, be sure to call out any user story that is not ready.

Answer (score 0):

User Stories provide good insight into how a product should behave.  While they seldom contain explicit testing criteria, there is often much implied that can be extracted from a user story which the test can develop into more formalized testing.

I like to break each user story down in three different passes:

1. First pass, identify functionality and features
2. Second pass, identify any limits imposed by a given environment, operating conditions, etc.  This can be things like performance/throughput, duration, security.
3. Third pass, identify:

   - Interfaces (other software, files,
     databases, peripherals, etc.)
   - Inputs and outputs (records, messages,
     files, reports, objects, etc.)
   - Configurations (System level,
     application level, hardware, network, etc.)
   - Usage scenarios (normal
     "happy path", error handling/recovery, backup, installation,etc.)

This may not be the perfect approach for every person or every project, but it is one approach that helps in developing a somewhat nebulous concept into a more concrete form.

Answer (score 0):

Talk to the developers, product owners and stakeholders. Figure out what was build and what needs testing.

If you are being assigned to a new product I would try some of the Tour heuristics:

- **Feature tour**: Move through the application and get familiar with all the controls and features you come across.
- **Complexity tour**: Find the five most complex things about the application.
- **Claims tour**: Find all the information in the product that tells you what the product does. Verify every claim
- **Configuration tour**: Attempt to find all the ways you can change settings in the product in a way that the application retains those settings.
- **Persona tour**: Imagine five users for the product and the information they would want from the product or the major features they would be interested in.

Research **[Exploratory testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/30079/is-there-any-standard-or-pattern-of-doing-exploratory-testing/30081#30081)** and figure out ways to come up with new test ideas.